# Why do I need to install certificates for an external URL when installing gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, certificate, lan

I am confused.

For now, I just want to self-host gitlab in my local home network without exposing it to the internet. Is this possible? If so can i do this without installing ca-certificates?

Why is gitlab force (?) me to expose my gitlab server to the internet?

Nothing else I've locally installed my NAS/Server requires ca certificates for me to connect to its webservice?: I can just go to `xyz.456.abc.123:port` in chrome

e.g. in this article, the public url is referenced: https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/2234/how-to-set-up-a-personal-gitlab-server/

Comment: What makes you think you have to expose your instance to the internet? You can use self-signed certs. You can obtain valid certs without being on the internet, too. You can also opt to not use SSL/TLS at all.

Comment: Right, I know I'm confused; I'm still a bit uncomfortable with certs and networking in general still. But the both the gitlab docker setup (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html) and the article in my OP both reference a public hostname or `EXTERNAL_URL`, in the form of e.g. `https://gitlab.example.com`. I guess I misunderstood both the docs and the article and providing this is in fact optional... I haven't been able to verify that empirically yet.

Comment: `external_url` can be a local IP address or hostname of a local computer if you want.

Comment: Is there a best practice? e.g. `"gitlab.$(uname -n)"` ?

Comment: It doesn't matter at all. Any valid hostname. Ideally, one that you already have a DNS entry for (like the computer's network hostname). You would probably setup your server to advertise the hostname `gitlab.mydomain.tld` but you can use whatever you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install certificates to use GitLab and you do not have to have GitLab exposed to the internet to have TLS security.

You can also opt to not use TLS/SSL at all if you really want. In fact, GitLab [does not use HTTPS by default](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#enable-https).

Using docker is probably the easiest way to demonstrate it's possible:

```
mkdir -p /opt/gitlab
export GITLAB_HOME=/opt/gitlab
docker run --detach \
  --hostname localhost \
  --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 \
  --name gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  -e GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG='external_url "http://localhost"' \
  gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest

# give it 15 or 20 minutes to start up

curl http://localhost
```

You can replace `http://localhost` in the `external_url` configuration with the computer hostname you want to use for your local server or even an IP address.